# JavaFX: Does each change in ListChangeListener has a single type of change

Tags: java, javafx

Just wondering if each `Change` object in a `ListChangeListener` contains only a single type of change.

```
while (c.next() {
    if (c.wasAdded()) {
    }
    if (c.wasRemoved()) {
    }
    if (c.wasUpdated()) {
    }
    if (c.wasPermutated()) {
    }
    if (c.wasReplaced()) {
    }
}

while (c.next() {
    if (c.wasAdded()) {
    }
    else if (c.wasRemoved()) {
    }
    else if (c.wasUpdated()) {
    }
    else if (c.wasPermutated()) {
    }
    else if (c.wasReplaced()) {
    }
}
```

Are there any difference between the two, and which would be the preferred way?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html ...

Comment: @kleopatra I re-read it carefully this time and to my surprise, I found my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A `ListChangeListener.Change` can contain a arbitrary combination of change types. There are 3 groups of states that are mutually exclusive:

1. Permutation changes
2. Add/remove/replace changes
3. Update changes

You iterate through these states using `ListChangeListener.Change.next()`. The order that these changes occur in is the same as in the above list: You first iterate through all permutation changes, then through the add/remove/replace changes and last through the update changes.

This means you could use code like this:

```
while (c.next()) {
    if (c.wasReplaced()) {
        // ...
    } else if (c.wasAdded()) {
        // ...
    } else if (c.wasRemoved()) {
        // ...
    } else if (c.wasPermutated()) {
        // ...
    } else if (c.wasUpdated()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You could reorder the checks in the `if/else if` as long as the check for a replace change happens before the checks for add and remove since a replace change means `wasRemoved` and `wasAdded` both yield `true`. (This is not the case in your second code snippet.)

Alternatively if you do not need to distinguish between add, remove and replace:

```
while (c.next()) {
    if (c.wasPermutated()) {
        // ...
    } else if (c.wasUpdated()) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // Handle add/remove/replace change
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With kleopatra's help I have found the answer. It is actually in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html) of `ListChangeListener.Change`, though the explanation is hidden right at the bottom.

> Note: in case the change contains multiple changes of different type,
>   these changes must be in the following order: permutation change(s),
>   add or remove changes, update changes This is because permutation
>   changes cannot go after add/remove changes as they would change the
>   position of added elements. And on the other hand, update changes must
>   go after add/remove changes because they refer with their indexes to
>   the current state of the list, which means with all add/remove changes
>   applied.

There is actually one confusing thing. This note tells us to do permutation -> add/remove -> update, but the example given is permutation -> update -> add/remove. I have decided the order given by the explanation definitely makes more sense. Moreover, the example shows that these 3 main types of changes would never happen within a single `Change` object, which contradicts with what the explanation says.

So my conclusion:

1. Treat each `Change` object as if it can have *all* types of changes in a single object. This means that `else if` should be avoided.
2. If you intend to handle *all* types of changes, then you should handle in the order of permutation -> add/remove -> update. I would have assumed that the order of add and remove wouldn't matter, but because of "replace" type of change, I would presume it's safer to handle remove before add.
3. "Replace" type of change can be ignored because it's equivalent to remove + add.